# Notepad++ Coffeescript Compiler

Tags: plugins, coffeescript, notepad++

How do I compile coffee script in Notepad++ to check that it works before reloading the web page? Are there any plugins available, particularly for the node.js coffeescript compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written as simple bat file at [https://github.com/obromios/coffee_short_black][1], that uses the Notepad++ run capability and can use the node.js compiler. It provides an easy way to view error messages and to view the compiled script. It is not a plugin, but is as easy to use as a plugin.